# Why this code is executing 2 times the same operation?

Tags: c++, boolean, return-value

So I have a basic **guess the number** game.

In my `int main` I have the three functions used to play it. I have a game loop surrounding these functions, with a `bool = false` and a `return value` set equal to my PlayAgain function.

Everything works well and good, but when you guess the right number, it asks if you want to play again twice for some reason.

I have tried removing one of the instances where i call the function in the `main`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include<string>


void PrintIntro();
void PlayGame();
bool PlayAgain();

int main() {

    bool bPlayAgain = false;
    do {
        PrintIntro();
        PlayGame();
        PlayAgain();     //I've tried removing this line
        bPlayAgain = PlayAgain(); //I've also played around with this one
    } while (bPlayAgain);

    return (0);
}

void PrintIntro()
{
    std::cout << "Guess a number between 1-100, fool!\n";
}

void PlayGame()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int> (time(0)));
    int HiddenNumber = rand();
    int Number = (HiddenNumber % 100) + 1;
    int Guess;

    do {
        std::cin >> Guess;
        if (Guess > Number) {
            std::cout << "You are too high bro!\n\n";
        }
        else if (Guess < Number) {
            std::cout << "You need to get higher bro!\n\n";
        }
        else if (Guess = Number) {
            std::cout << "You are just high enough, you win!\n\n";
        }
    } while (Guess != Number);
}

bool PlayAgain()
{
    std::string Response = "";
    std::cout << "Would you like to play again? yes or no." << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, Response);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return (Response[0] == 'y') || (Response[0] == 'Y');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community Nicholas. Although it appears that you have done some research into this before asking, I would encourage you to continue to debug your code. It's very likely that this is a simple bug (calling the PlayAgain method more than expected), and StackOverflow really isn't the right website for this kind of debugging help.

Comment: _"`//I've tried removing this line`"_ It definitely needs to be removed.

Comment: I believe the code `PlayAgain(); bPlayAgain = PlayAgain();` is calling the function two times? I do not understand in your text if you have tried removing one of them.

Answer (score 1):

here is the code fixed. I added a new boolean function called Game that plays the game and returns true if the player want to re-play.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include<string>


void PrintIntro();
void PlayGame();
bool PlayAgain();
bool Game();

int main() {

    bool bPlayAgain = Game();
    while(bPlayAgain == true)
    {
        bPlayAgain = Game();
    }
    return (0);
}

void PrintIntro()
{
    std::cout << "Guess a number between 1-100, fool!\n";
}

void PlayGame()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int> (time(0)));
    int HiddenNumber = rand();
    int Number = (HiddenNumber % 100) + 1;
    int Guess;

    do {
        std::cin >> Guess;
        if (Guess > Number) {
            std::cout << "You are too high bro!\n\n";
        }
        else if (Guess < Number) {
            std::cout << "You need to get higher bro!\n\n";
        }
        else if (Guess = Number) {
            std::cout << "You are just high enough, you win!\n\n";
        }
    } while (Guess != Number);
}

bool PlayAgain()
{
    char Response;
    std::cout << "Would you like to play again? yes or no." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Response;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return (Response == 'y') || (Response == 'Y');
}

bool Game()
{
    PrintIntro();
    PlayGame();
    bool selection = PlayAgain();

    return selection;
}
```